# React js Material UI expansion panel disable by code

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, state

I am trying to disable React Material Accordian / Expansion Panel by State Properties . normally disabled attribute is doing it . like

```
    <ExpansionPanel >
    <ExpansionPanelDetails>
    </ExpansionPanelDetails>
    </ExpansionPanel>

    <ExpansionPanel disabled > ---> this will disabled
    <ExpansionPanelDetails>
    </ExpansionPanelDetails>
    </ExpansionPanel>
```

but i want to disable like

```
  <ExpansionPanel disabled="stateProperty?true:false" >
```

can it be possible with ExpansionPanel  ? i googled . but not found much relevant ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
<ExpansionPanel disabled={!!stateProperty}>
```

The `!!` part casts the `stateProperty` variable to `Boolean`

Comment: you are always been helpful for me in react :) .. accepted answer